# Posting feeds in facebook, can't use the API

Tags: php, facebook, feed

I'm getting a -

> Call to undefined method

when I try to use feed API functions like `registerBundleTemplates` and `feed_publishUserAction`.

Google has led me to believe that I need to call a function called `useBetaApiServer`, but I can't find any example on how to call it with PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved using call_method.
Very useful for solving discrepancies between the libs you have and the documented libs.